# How to upload an image using Ajax?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jhtml, file-upload

I need to upload an image to the server via AJAX, but the server comes back to the page with request, although server doesn't send anything.

ajax:

```
function uploadServer($el) {
    var fileUpload = $el.get(0);
    var file = fileUpload.files[0];
    var url;
    if (file) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('image', file);

        var request = {
            'option': 'com_ajax',
            'module': 'constructor',
            'method': 'uplodeImage',
            'val'   :  data,
            'format': 'raw',
        };
        console.log(request);
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            data: request,
            success: function (response) {
                url = response;
            }
        }).done(function(response){
            url = response;
        });
    }
    $('#debug').html(url);
    return url;
```

module:

```
class modConstructorHelper
{
    // Загрузка изображений во временную папку 
    public static function uplodeImageAjax() {
        jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
        jimport('joomla.application.input.files');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [video tutorial using the file field type](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o482sK4DxkM&index=56&list=PLQRGFI8XZ_wtGvPQZWBfDzzlERLQgpMRE) then [drag and drop Ajax tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvzDyVQyHDI&list=PLQRGFI8XZ_wtGvPQZWBfDzzlERLQgpMRE&index=57), it may help. But it is for a component.